# Several CSS classes with just one property that's different?

Tags: html, css

This is a simple question, I just don't know how to search for it in the web.

I have three `CSS` classes: `.header`, `.cell`, `.footer`. They look like the following:

```
.header
{
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    width:130px;
    height:20px; 
    background-color: Yellow; 
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
.cell
{
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    width:130px;
    height:85px; 
    background-color: Yellow; 
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
.footer
{
    display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    width:130px;
    height:40px; 
    background-color: Yellow; 
    border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

The only difference between all these classes is the `height` property. How can I simplify this code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `,` to separate the elements in the selector list for the common properties:

```
.foo, .bar {
   color: red;
}

.foo {
   font-size: 120%;
}

.bar {
   font-size: 80%;
}
```

This'll make both `.foo` and `.bar` be red, but have different text sizes.

Comment: Note user-defined classes need to be preceded by `.` - because `foo` and `bar` are not native classes, it would read `.foo, .bar { ...`.